# Magento 1.9 - cycle Foreach, result blank content

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm trying to write cycle foreach, for insert my categories in the table with 3 rows and 4 columns. The code is this:

```
$i = 0;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($i % 12 == 0) {
      // Table ID dont need to be rounded, because $i % 12 == 0, so $i / 12 is integer, not float...
      echo ''."\n";
    }

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
      echo ''."\n";
    }

    echo ''.$row['name_file'].''."\n";

    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
      echo ''."\n";
    }

    if ($i % 12 == 11) {
      echo ''."\n";
    }

    $i++;
  }

  if ($i % 3 > 0) {
    echo ''."\n";
  }

  if ($i % 12 > 0) {
    echo ''."\n";
  }
}
```

When i reload home page content is empty, where is error?

Answer (score 0):

your following code has been put out of the while loop. it should come inside while loop

```
if ($i % 3 > 0) {
      echo ''."\n";
    }

    if ($i % 12 > 0) {
      echo ''."\n";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man for reply. But I tried to do as you say but still without success. What else could I do? Thank you.

Comment: update your code in the question

Comment: Sorry man but I can not make display html tags inside the echo quotes. However inside the empty quotes there would be the opening and closing tags of the table. The code is to. I tried to do as you suggested but to no avail. It always appears empty content. How could I do? Thank you.